# Why does my website not recognize Handlebars when it works perfectly locally?

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

Locally my website works, but on the webserver, it doesn't display the part I programmed with Handlebars. When I open up the dev-tools, It gives me the error that Handlebars is not defined and that it failed to load it as a resource.
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tg8Gr.png)

My file structure looks like this-
index.html
handlebarLibrary.js

pages
- products
- products.html
- handleBarProducts.js
- products.css

I am trying to use the handlebars on the products page. Locally it works fine, but on the website its not working.

Comment: Can you check the Network tab to see where it tries to load the handlebarLibrary.js from? Might be that its trying to get it from the wrong url.

Comment: No, it tries to get it from the file, but returns error 404, which means not found. I checked and its there locally. When I open the code locally it works perfectly, but on the website it doesn't load it. The website is mapleelectronics.com. The issue is on the products page.

Answer (score 0):

After checking out the site I noticed this:
`Request URL: https://mapleelectronics.com/handleBarLibrary.js`
Its trying to load `handleBarLibrary.js`, with a capital `B`, but it should be `handlebarLibrary.js`

This one loads: `https://mapleelectronics.com/handlebarLibrary.js`
This one doesnt:`https://mapleelectronics.com/handleBarLibrary.js`

Change the file name in your HTML, should work